# AWS Cognito Signup Lambda Trigger -> Create User Profile

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, triggers, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I currently have a "post-confirmation" lambda trigger configured in my Cognito user pool. How do I edit this lambda function so that when a new user is created - a new "Profile" Object is created in an existing "Profile" DynamoDB table.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of what I have done and adapted it to your request.

Note, `postConfirmation` is triggered too for the forgot password workflow.

Please do your own testing before using it:

```
/* Amplify Params - DO NOT EDIT
    API_HIREDINCHINAREMASTER_PROFILETABLE_ARN
    API_HIREDINCHINAREMASTER_PROFILETABLE_NAME
    ENV
    REGION
Amplify Params - DO NOT EDIT */

/**
 * @type {import('@types/aws-lambda').APIGatewayProxyHandler}
 */
var dynamodb = require("aws-sdk/clients/dynamodb");
var ddb = new dynamodb({ region: "eu-west-1" });

exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
  console.log("EVENT", event);
  console.log("CONTEXT", context);

  let date = new Date();

  // As this is a PostConfirmation trigger, it can be triggered by other events
  // We only want to run the code below if the triggerSource is PostConfirmation_ConfirmSignUp
  // The other one is possibly "forgot_password" (which we don't want to run this code for)

  const valueTrigger = event.triggerSource;
  const confirmSignUp = "PostConfirmation_ConfirmSignUp";

  // If the triggerSource is PostConfirmation_ConfirmSignUp, then we know that the user has just signed up
  if (valueTrigger === confirmSignUp) {
    // We only want to run the code below if the user has a sub (unique user ID)
    if (event.request.userAttributes.sub) {


      // I will use their custom group to determine which parameters need to be passed into the DynamoDB call
      const paramsToUse = event.request.userAttributes["custom:group"] === "Candidates" ? candidateParams : employerParams;

      // These are the parameters we need to pass to DynamoDB for the initial user creation
      let params = {
        Item: {
          id                : { S: event.request.userAttributes["custom:id"] },
          owner             : { S: event.request.userAttributes.sub },
          group             : { S: event.request.userAttributes["custom:group"] },
          email             : { S: event.request.userAttributes.email },
          createdAt         : { S: date.toISOString() },
          updatedAt         : { S: date.toISOString() }
        },
        TableName: API_HIREDINCHINAREMASTER_PROFILETABLE_NAME,
      };
      console.log("PARAMS", params);

      try {
        await ddb.putItem(params).promise();
        console.log("Successfully added to DynamoDB Table");
      } catch (err) {
        console.error("ERROR", err);
      }
      console.log("Success: Everything executed correctly");
      context.done(null, event);
    } else {
      // Nothing to do, the user's email ID is unknown
      console.error("ERROR: Nothing was written to DynamoDB");
      context.done(null, event);
    }
  } else {
    console.log("Not Confirm Signup, thus not running the code");
    context.done(null, event);
  }
};
```